# Get the internal details of the items in recycler view if the items are shuffeled

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a recycler view, which consists of list. The items in the list have their own details like this (each item will have image, id, name, description), and the items are shuffeled, not in order.

Example : recyclerview item position = 0,  list item id= 7.

recyclerview item position = 1,  list item id= 5.

recyclerview item position = 2,  list item id= 12.

So i need to get the list item id on recycler on click. If i click on recyclerview position = 0, If i have to get the item id as 7. So that i can work on that furthur based on that id.

My example code is

```
    recommendedrecyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recommended_recycler_view);
    recommendedrecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recommendedrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),OrientationHelper.VERTICAL,true));
    recommendedrecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

I am getting data from server and setting it to adapter

```
  setrecommendedAppsContent(response.body().getData());

    public void setrecommendedAppsContent(List<FeaturedAppsData> data){
    if (data!=null&&data.size()>0) {
        recommendedAdapter = new RecommendedAdapter(mCurrentContext, data);
        recommendedrecyclerView.setAdapter(recommendedAdapter);
        recommendedAdapter.setClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class RecommendedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecommendedAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private Context context;
private List<FeaturedAppsData> itemsData;
private ClickListener clicklistener = null;
public TextView recommendedAppTitle,recommendedAppCategory,recommendedAppDescription;
public ImageView recommendedAppIcon;
Button recommendedBtn;
String appId;

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clicklistener = clickListener;
}

public RecommendedAdapter(Context context, List<FeaturedAppsData> itemsData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsData = itemsData;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.recommendedAppTitle.setText(itemsData.get(position).getName());
    holder.recommendedAppCategory.setText(itemsData.get(position).getApp_description());
    holder.recommendedAppDescription.setText(itemsData.get(position).getOffer_description());
    holder.recommendedAppBtn.setText(itemsData.get(position).getButton_text());
    String imageUrl = String.valueOf(itemsData.get(position).getImage().getUrl());
    Glide.with(context).load(ApiConstant.ApiBaseUrl + imageUrl).into(recommendedAppIcon);
    appId=itemsData.get(position).getId();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int size = 0;
    if (itemsData != null && itemsData.size() > 0) {
        size = itemsData.size();

    }
    return size;
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView recommendedAppTitle,recommendedAppCategory,recommendedAppDescription,offerDescription,offerDetailDescription,rewardDetail;
    public ImageView recommendedAppIcon;
    public Button recommendedAppBtn;
    public ArrayList<FeaturedAppsData> dataItems;
    private Context context;

    public ItemViewHolder(Context context, View itemView, int viewType) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = context;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        recommendedAppTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recommended_app_title);
        recommendedAppCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recommended_app_category);
        recommendedAppDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recommended_app_description);
        recommendedAppIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recommended_app_icon);
        recommendedAppBtn=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recommended_app_card_btn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (clicklistener != null) {
            clicklistener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}


@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recommended_item_layout, parent, false);
    recommendedAppIcon=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.recommended_app_icon);

    return new ItemViewHolder(context, view, viewType);
}

}
```

I am not sure of the Onclick method. So please suggest me as required along with Onclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setOnClickListener` inside the ViewHolder is a good way.

Considering your current solution, the easiest way is to change the ClickListener interface, put the data inside the Holder during `onBindViewHolder`  and then pass it to the listener during `onClick`. Like this:

Change the view holder fields to:

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView recommendedAppTitle,recommendedAppCategory,recommendedAppDescription,offerDescription,offerDetailDescription,rewardDetail;
    public ImageView recommendedAppIcon;
    public Button recommendedAppBtn;
    public FeaturedAppsData data; // <<< ADD THIS 
    // remove that u don't need public ArrayList<FeaturedAppsData> dataItems;
    // remove that u don't need private Context context;
    ... the rest of your holder
```

then inside `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.data = itemsData.get(position);
    ... the rest on bind
```

then inside `onClick`, inside the holder:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (clicklistener != null) {
        clicklistener.itemClicked(v, data.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: so with this how can i get item id?

Comment: inside id part of `FeaturedAppsData` ?

Comment: Actually i am using onclick interface for two more recycler views. So in OnClick method, if i am returning the FeaturedAppData data instead of int value, it is giving error for other two recycler method on click actions.

Comment: I've edited my solution then. Now it's passing just the ID.

Comment: error [errors: ‘Could not find feed with the id <id>] .This is the error response i got while executing. Means it is not taking the id value of the list item. Maybe it is taking the recycler view item position

Comment: I can't know because you didn't show enough code. I gave you the answer based off a best assumption from my part. But regardless of the specific implementation detail, I would ask you to understand the IDEA of the answer and then modify it to your needs.
Alternatively, just use my library that have `OnItemClickListener` implemented correctly https://github.com/budius/recyclerviewtools

Comment: I appreciate your support, but the only thing i am looking for is finally to get the id for the items in the list. There is no other code more than this, except for data classes which i got from pojo for retrofit.

Comment: and I showed you how to get the data class inside the OnClick method, how you get the ID from it, depends on the POJO.